# Modifying XML file from string source - how to do it?

Tags: python, xml

I have a problem, where I want to change some lines in my `XML`, but this `XML` is not in file, it is in `string`. I am using `Python 3.x` and lib `xml.etree.ElementTree` for this purpose.

I have these piece of code which I know works for files in project, but as I said, I want no files, only operations on string sources.

```
source_tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(source_config))
source_tree_root = ET.fromstring(source_config)
for item in source_tree_root.iter('generation'):
            item.text = item.text.replace(self.firstarg, self.secondarg)
```

This works, but I don't know how to save it. I tried 
`source_tree.write(source_config, encoding='latin-1')` but this doesn't work (treats all `XML` as a name).

Comment: Just to clarify, your goal is to convert the changed XML back to a string (as opposed to writing it to a file), correct?

Comment: Good question @Tomalak. I saw "_don't know how to save it_" and "_I tried source_tree.write_" and assumed a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need both `source_tree` and `source_tree_root`. By having both, you're creating two separate things. When you write using `source_tree`, you don't get the changes made to `source_tree_root`.

Try creating an ElementTree from `source_tree_root` (which is just an Element), like this (untested since you didn't supply an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))...

```
source_tree_root = ET.fromstring(source_config)
for item in source_tree_root.iter('generation'):
            item.text = item.text.replace(self.firstarg, self.secondarg)

ET.ElementTree(source_tree_root).write("output.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I thought that you were using lxml.  My bad.  Well here is how you would do it with lxml.  I think that lxml is superior.

Here is the basic way of parsing a string into an XML document.

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring(yourstring)

for e in doc.xpath('//sometagname'):
    e.set('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: The OP isn't using lxml; they're using ElementTree. It also appears that they're setting the text value; not an attribute.

Comment: Yeah, as someone that uses lxml all the time I glossed right over the xml.etree part. 
 Well, I just showed how to modify the doc; setting an attribute is modifying the document.

Comment: "_I think that lxml is superior._" - I agree 100%. :-)